How to add key bindings to Fabulous View/Window?
I am trying to understand how to bind a set of keyboard handlers to MainView/MainWindow during initialization of a desktop application.
First I tried to do that with subscription
        let keyDownSub dispatch =
            applicationRef.Value.MainView.KeyDown.Subscribe(fun eventArgs ->
                match eventArgs.Key with
                | Key.Up -> Msg.Up
                | Key.Down -> Msg.Down
                | Key.Left -> Msg.Left
                | Key.Right -> Msg.Right
                | _ -> Msg.Empty
                |> dispatch)

        [ [ nameof keyDownSub ], keyDownSub ]


To access the application I used either let app = FabApplication.Current or applicationRef.Value. In both cases I got NullReferenceException.
Then I tried to add Loaded message and handler but realized that I don't know how to dynamically dispatch KeyDown events.
I understand that Fabulous is "mobile first" library and keyboard is processed in a different way comparing to desktop. Could anyone give me a general idea of working with keyboard in Fabulous?
